# Run jQuery function everytime (In case bounce effects)

Tags: jquery

Simple question, How to run this jQuery bounce hover below always bounce. So I do not need to hover it and it will bounce every time.

Here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".button").hover(function(){
            $(".button img")
            .animate({top:"-10px"}, 200).animate({top:"-4px"}, 200) // first jump
            .animate({top:"-7px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100) // second jump
            .animate({top:"-6px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100); // the last jump
        });
    });
```

Comment: Use `setInterval` to run a function periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `setInterval` and timer = total time delay by animation

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".button img")
    .animate({top:"-10px"}, 200).animate({top:"-4px"}, 200) // first jump
    .animate({top:"-7px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100) // second jump
    .animate({top:"-6px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100); // the last jump
},600);
```

or recursive function

```
function bounce(){
    $(".button img")
        .animate({top:"-10px"}, 200).animate({top:"-4px"}, 200)
        .animate({top:"-7px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100)
        .animate({top:"-6px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100,function(){
        bounce();
    }); 
}
bounce();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the bounce code in a function, and call it from the callback of the last animation so it will restart:

```
function bounce_img(img) {
    img.animate({top:"-10px"}, 200).animate({top:"-4px"}, 200) // first jump
        .animate({top:"-7px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100) // second jump
        .animate({top:"-6px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100,  // last jump
                function() {bounce_img(img);}); // restart
}

$(document).ready() {
    $(".button img").each(function() {
        bounce_img($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: better solution then setInterval IMO, +1

Answer (score 0):

This will do just change the 2000 to any time you want (after you animation finished).

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    $(".button img")
    .animate({top:"-10px"}, 200).animate({top:"-4px"}, 200) // first jump
    .animate({top:"-7px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100) // second jump
    .animate({top:"-6px"}, 100).animate({top:"-4px"}, 100);
}, 2000);
```

then if you want it to stop just call

```
clearInterval(timer);
```